# How to display images from S3/Paperclip/Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm setting up configurations for s3, but images doesn't display.

[heroku site](https://insta-pin.herokuapp.com/)

heroku log - doesn't show me any error about it.

[github repo](https://github.com/gemcave/insta-pin)

I don't know where is problem.

Comment: Edit your question, rather than posting additional info in the comments. Also, try to reduce the problem/question to a single issue. See [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build image URLs in your application looking like this:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/instapin-rails/photos/images/000/000/002/medium/38847662_1905162256447081_1160841501610082304_n.jpg
```

But your Amazon configuration requires this format:

```
http://instapin-rails.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/images/000/000/002/medium/38847662_1905162256447081_1160841501610082304_n.jpg
```

Just change the prefix (host and the first path segment) and it should work.